# django asking to add default values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to django and I am facing some problem.

This was my previous model.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()
```

I added some data to this model.
After that I added one more field to it.
Now my model looks like this..

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

When I ran the command `python manage.py makemigrations` I got the following error which is obvious.

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'age' to blog without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I don't want to add **default** so I **deleted** the table contents by accessing db.sqlite3

But again after running `python manage.py makemigrations` I am getting the same error.why?

Comment: Its not an error. You are trying to add a field to the database without allowing to be null and with no initial value. If you dont care about the current data in your table, then select option 1 and enter `None` as the default to set for now. It should migrate without any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you have deleted the table, any changes to your Django model will always refer to the previous migration of that model, hence it still requires you to set a default value. If you're still in development, then you could delete the migrations for that model and then makemigrations again. But, this is terrible practice and you should never do this unless you are consciously squashing your models, the better way is to do what Django is telling you and set a default. This'll help in the long run anyways with error handling.

The other answers address how to set defaults quite well.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a new field (i.e., column) to a database table, that field applies to all rows in the table...the existing ones and any new ones. If the field cannot be `null`, then some value must be specified for all of the existing rows.

By default, `IntegerField()` is non-nullable. This explains why you are getting the warning. You have a few options:

- You can choose a default "one-off" initial value like Django suggests. All existing rows will use this value for the new field.
- Assign your own values to each existing row for the new field.
- Use the `blank` and `null` arguments in your model field to allow the field to accept null values.

For the last option, you'd do this like so:

`models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`

But that might not be the best choice depending on your use case. If nullable values don't make sense for your field, I would avoid making the field support nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Django models fields are null set to true by default.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can solve this:

- Delete the Blog table from the database.
- Delete the **migrations** folder from the app that contains Blog model.
- Remove all data from **django_migrations** table.
- Now run **makemigrations** and then **migrate** command.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Django is telling you, then you can remove the `default` attribute if you don't need it. But it's a good practice to keep it anyway